# Sitecore: get translation by language

Tags: sitecore, translation, sitecore8

I'm building an automated task in Sitecore 8.0 Update 2 to automatically send out some emails. These emails need to be in different languages.

I've always used this approach:

```cs
Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByDomain("General Dictionary", "some-key");
```

However, when I try to use this code:

```cs
Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage("some-key", Sitecore.Context.Language);
```

it doesn't work (even if I simply use the current context language).
I can find little to no documentation about this. What would I have to do to get this to work?

Comment: Is this a scheduled task in Sitecore. If so, I don't think there is a proper `Sitecore.Context` there (or `Sitecore.Context.Language`). You should write some code to get the proper language for that mail first, and then use it instead of calling `Sitecore.Context.Language`. Try to debug your code and see what language is used.

Comment: I also tried this but it had the same effect. It always simply returns the key value ( checked the translation dictionary, the key i'm looking for exists )

Comment: Does this translation exist in `core` or `master` database? What are the `Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase` and `Sitecore.Context.Database` during your task execution? Database used in traslation is `database = Sitecore.Context.ContentDatabase ?? Sitecore.Context.Database ?? Factory.GetDatabase("core")`

Comment: Are you using Dictionary Domains? i.e. different dictionary per website? If so, since you have no Site Context, it can't resolve the dictionary and will fallback. You may need to wrap your code in a `using (new SiteContextSwitcher(siteContext)) { ... }` statement

Answer (score 3):

As @jammykam suggested, Maybe you need to wrap your code with SiteContextSwitcher class, since Sitecore.Context.Database might be referencing Core database during Task agent execution because the context site is "**scheduler**"
So your code should be:

```cs
using (var switcher = new SiteContextSwitcher((SiteContextFactory.GetSiteContext("website"))))
{
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: Will that work? You didn't include the call to `SiteContextSwitcher`

Comment: @jammykam i added it now, missed it by mistake

Answer (score 0):

I've checked Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.TextByLanguage method and it works.

Could you please, check that translation exist in the 'core' database. Sitecore used to store dictionary items in the 'master' database, but right now it stored translation in the 'core' database.

1. Switch shell to 'core' database.
2. Go to the Dictionary: /sitecore/system/Dictionary
3. Find your key by the first letter in the string: "some-key" -> "S".
4. Check that translation exists for this key.

   - Select DictionaryKey item > "some-key"
   - Switch between languages and check whether translation is exist.

Comment: That's not true. Dictionary translation works using fallback, first looking in defined DictionaryDomain, then in master db `/sitecore/system/Dictionary` finally falling back to core database. Note he's talking about custom dictionary items, NOT default sitecore UI labels.